# Grails Auto-Complete for Form.gsp

Tags: jquery, grails

I want to implement auto-complete to the majority of fields that I have on my form to reduce the users time spent inputting values. I've looked around for a simple step-by-step guide for using JQuery to achieve this but I haven't found any that I can follow. I'm completely new to JQuery and this will be my first experience of it.

Is it possible to not have to use JQuery and just have autocomplete retrieve a bunch of values from a list rather than from a database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to not have to use JQuery and just have autocomplete retrieve a bunch of values from a list rather than from a database?

[**Here's a jQuery autocomplete plugin**](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) that allows you to retrieve the list of suggestions either via AJAX or from static data - see the `lookup` option for the latter.